# extract values from pre-defined template

Tags: c#, regex, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

I created one automated power automate flow - which executed on any incoming email and performs `unbound action` - a `custom action` "ValidateEmailBody" written in C# and registered in CRM plugin registration.

I am using the custom regex to read values passed in the pre-defined template, and so far it is working fine but now I want to make it little user compatible.

> The requirement here is - **to trim the preceding and tailing spaces** which are by mistake added by mail sender so that custom action can fetch the record properly.

Below is the working template with given regex:

**Regex**:

```
var templatePattern = new Regex(@"Case title:[ ]{1,}(?<caseTitle>.*?)\n{1,}Client:[ ]{1,}(?<client>.*?)\n{1,}Origin:[ ]{1,}(?<origin>.*?)\n{1,}Contact:[ ]{1,}(?<contact>.*?)\n{1,}DSM:[ ]{1,}(?<dsm>.*?)\n{1,}CSM:[ ]{1,}(?<csm>.*?)\n{1,}Assigned To:[ ]{1,}(?<assignedTo>.*?)\n{1,}Due Date:[ ]{1,}(?<dueDate>.*?)\n{1,}Description:[ ]{1,}(?<desc>.*?)$");
```

**Explanation of regex**:

```
[]{1,} -> Can have one or more spaces
?<groupName>.*? -> Creates a group name to extract the word(s)
\n{1,} --> Allows one or more new line
$ --> End of line
```

**Template**:

> Case title: Sample Test case 9
> Client: 8688211
> Origin: Email
> Contact: testing@me.com
> DSM: testContact1
> CSM: testContact1
> Assigned To: testing@me.com
> Due Date: 06/28/2023
> Description: Sample description 9

Now, I want to trim the extra spaces from the value and just read the value in **C#** e.g. refer below template for that:

**New possible template**:

> Case title:     Sample Test case 9
> Client:       8688211
> Origin: Email
> Contact:     testing@me.com
> DSM: testContact1
> CSM: testContact1
> Assigned To:     testing@me.com
> Due Date:      06/28/2023
> Description: Sample description 9

To achieve that, what changes I need to make into my custom action or in regex?

> FYR, I am reading this value because based on that I need to create a new record in the CRM - so if there are additional spaces or new lines will stop me in doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the values over the full lines, you can use `\S` to match a non whitespace character inside the capture group, and then follow with optional spaces until the following newline.

Note that you are matching only spaces. If you want to match spaces without newline characters, then you can use `[\p{Zs}\t]+`

Constructs like `[ ]{1,}` can be shortened to  `+` and `\n{1,}` to `\n+`

```
^Case title: +(?<caseTitle>.*\S) *\n+Client: +(?<client>.*?\S) *\n+Origin: +(?<origin>.*?\S) *\n+Contact: +(?<contact>.*?\S) *\n+DSM: +(?<dsm>.*?) *\n+CSM: +(?<csm>.*?\S) *\n+Assigned To: +(?<assignedTo>.*?\S) *\n+Due Date: +(?<dueDate>.*?\S) *\n+Description: +(?<desc>.*?\S) *$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yqThYj/1)

So every separate line has the same structure for the pattern:

```
 +                  -> Can have one or more spaces
(?<groupName>.*?\S  -> Creates a group name to extract the word(s) ending on a non whitspace character
 *\n+               -> One or more new lines preceded by optional spaces
 *$                 -> End of line, preceded by optional spaces
```

Comment: That is helpful. It turns out when I convert `HTML to Text` in `Power Automate` it just have some different special character. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/qav0QK/1) is the link where there are unknown/unhandled special characters. How can I handle that?

Comment: @PratikSoni By making use of `[\p{Zs}\t]` instead of a space like https://regex101.com/r/L9l7uR/1